# Can we use simple present tense here?

Tags: tense, present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

[Here](https://www.samsung.com/ca/support/mobile-devices/can-you-use-phone-while-charging/) I found the following sentence.

> When you use your phone while charging, the battery is charging at a slower rate than normal to allow enough power for the ongoing usage.

Can I use simple present tense here? Because they are talking about what normally happens when we use phone with charging on. And simple present tense is used to describe facts.

> When you use your phone while charging, the battery **charges** at a slower rate than normal to allow enough power for the ongoing usage.

Is the above sentence correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use the present tense in this context. There is no problem there.

However, your sentence is not well constructed. The implication, however unlikely, is that your are charging (around) rather than the phone. Simply adding **it** after **charging** resolves the problem.

You could also simplify your sentence without losing any meaning. As it stands, it is overwritten.

To write: **When you use your phone while charging it, the battery charges at a slower rate (than normal)** is quite sufficient. It's hardly necessary to spell out the reason although, grammatically, it's quite correct.

Comment: Charging around means?

Comment: Imagine that your sentence was: **If you use your phone while running, the battery is charging......** The question is: **Are you running or is the phone running?** The statement is ambiguous. The same is true for your sentence. Who or what is doing the charging? **Charging around** means running around. **The kids were charging around the playground.** But if you told a cavalry officer: **If you use your phone while charging, ...** the statement would mean something quite different to your intention.

Comment: Ok. got it. Well, I've borrowed this sentence from the website given in link.